# Rails Joining together multiple tables

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

So I am trying to create a news feed of sorts but I am unsure as to how to make the queries.

I have a user model, a model for followed locations and a model for followed users. And then I have a model for comments. I need to grab all the comments from users that a user follows and all comments from a location that a user follows and I have to put these together.

I'm not that familiar with how to do this in sql or rails. Can anyone link me to an article or the docs where I might find how to do this?

If you need more information just comment what else I should include because I was unsure what to include in the post.

The comments model looks like this and it is polymorphic and can be posted to locations and events

```
create_table :comments do |t|
  t.text :text
  t.integer :user_id
  t.integer :commentable_id
  t.string :commentable_type
```

And then there is two separate tables for following users and following locations

```
create_table :followed_locations do |t|
  t.integer :user_id
  t.integer :location_id

create_table :followed_users do |t|
  t.integer :user_id
  t.integer :followed_id
```

Comment: Posting a small snippet of code that demonstrates how your models are defined would go a long way towards answering this question more precisely.

Comment: How are your comments related to the other elements? Are they polymorphic, or do you have location comments and user comments as different models?

Comment: I'll post a correction to my answer based on the model info you just gave.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how the model associations would look:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :comments, as: :commentable
    has_many :followed_locations
    has_many :followed_users

    def followed_items
        followed_locations.map(&:location).flatten + followed_users.map(&:followed).flatten
    end
end

class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :comments, as: :commentable
end

class FollowedUser < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :followed, class_name: 'User'
end

class FollowedLocation < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :location
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :commentable, polymorphic: true
end
```

The code above defines the relationships among all the models, and adds one User instance method to collect all the items (locations or users) that a given user follows. Now you can gather all the comments for users/locations that a single user is following, like so:

```
user.followed_items.map(&:comments).flatten
```

This will gather all the followed items for a user (both locations and other users), get a list of all their comments, then flatten them into a simple array. If you want to sort them, my creation for example, tack that onto the end:

```
user.followed_items.map(&:comments).flatten.sort_by(&:created_at)
```

There are ways to optimize this, but at this point you probably just want to focus on getting the concepts down.

UPDATE:

I've created a simple Rails 4 app that implements this solution, and published it on github:

https://github.com/rubycuts/so26169791

Comment: I did this and try to use the code and it doesn't work it gives me a undefined method `comments' for nil:NilClass error. With the line of code @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @items = @user.followed_items.map(&:comments).flatten

Comment: I quickly created a Rails 4 app to test the code I gave you, and it works. I added a link to the github repository at the end of my answer above. Please look over your code to ensure you implemented my suggestion exactly, and let me know how it goes.

Comment: Yeh my code is literally the exact same as yours and its still giving me the undefined method `comments' for nil:NilClass

Comment: Could you paste your followed_items method? That's the source of your error.

Comment: Sorry, I think I know the problem. You have a FollowedUser or FollowedLocation record where the followed_id or location_id is either nil, or points to a record that doesn't exist. This is a data integrity issue. You can quick-fix it by saying "user.followed_items.compact.map(&:comments).flatten", but it's a band-aid solution. You need to find the broken join records.

Comment: This works perfectly now thanks so much! I'll accept your answer but is there a way to order all this data by the created_at col?

Comment: Sure, I added that to the answer above. Happy coding :)